# Iterating Gravity Forms Repeatable Lists in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This question is a bit specific to Gravity Forms, but it is a common issue found in web development with  jQuery.

Gravity Forms allows you to use repeatable lists: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_column_input_content

These are essentially just fields which give the +/- to be added/removed which I'm assuming they just get cloned.

What I am trying to do is have a Number next to each one (First field says 1. [field], Second: 2. [field] and so forth.)

My code:

```
$.each($(".gfield_list input"), function(index,elem) {
    $("<span>"+(index+1)+". </span>").prependTo($(this).parent());
})
```

Which is then hooked to the on("click", function() {}), however is not producing the desired results.

If anyone could help, this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate solution that uses CSS rather than jQuery.

http://gravitywiz.com/numbering-gravity-forms-list-field-rows/